# JSONModel Optional and Ignore are not respected

Tags: ios, json, jsonmodel

I have these properties in the header file.

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString<Optional>* guidId;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSDate* created_at;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber<Ignore>* longitude;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber<Ignore>* latitude;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber* altitude;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber* relative_altitude;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber* value;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString<Optional>* scale;
@property (copy, readonly, nonatomic, getter=getReadingTypeDescription) NSString* name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) WEEReadingType readingType;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* location;
```

Though it is strange Optional and Ignore are not respected.

In the implementation file I override these two methods.

```
// This one because when converting to JSON from Model I need specific properties only and Ignore is not for this purpose

    - (NSString *)toJSONString
        {
        return [super toJSONStringWithKeys:
            @[
            @"guidId",
            @"location",
            @"altitude",
            @"relative_altitude",
            @"scale",
            @"name",
            @"value",
            @"created_at"
            ]];
        }


// And this one for the enum property that I want to ignore, but I found out I get an error when using [JSONModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:json error:&error] that Optional or Ignore is not respected.

    + (BOOL)propertyIsIgnored:(NSString *)propertyName
        {
        if ([propertyName isEqualToString:@"readingType"] ||
            [propertyName isEqualToString:@"guidId"] ||
            [propertyName isEqualToString:@"longitude"] ||
            [propertyName isEqualToString:@"latitude"])
            {
            return YES;
            }
        return NO;
        }
```

Example of JSON I need to convert to my model.

```
[
{
"created_at": "2015-03-20T19:26:28.000Z",
"location": [
40.70739851802653,
-74.005788154969
],
"altitude": 4.063048774263429,
"relative_altitude": 0.0,
"name": "pressure",
"value": 1014.718704223633,
"scale": "mb"
},
{
"created_at": "2015-03-20T19:26:28.000Z",
"location": [
40.70739851802653,
-74.005788154969
],
"altitude": 4.063048774263429,
"relative_altitude": 0.0,
"name": "pressure",
"value": 1014.718704223633,
"scale": null
}
]
```

The above with `[JSONModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:json error:&error]` will throw the following error.

```
Error Domain=JSONModelErrorDomain Code=1 "Invalid JSON data: Value of required model key scale is null" UserInfo=0x170265cc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid JSON data: Value of required model key scale is null, kJSONModelKeyPath=[46].scale}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Did you subclass the `Optional` protocol? As you did with ignore properties, why don't you use the class method to define the optional values?

Comment: No I didn't, sorry about that, I just prefixed the naming cause I use the library in a framework, and I do this to avoid duplicate symbols.

Comment: Just try using `+(BOOL)propertyIsOptional:(NSString*)propertyName`

Comment: wow, didn't even think about it, that did the job. Still though can't explain why the protocol assignment does not work!

Comment: Maybe is something about the name refactoring of the classes and protocols

Comment: I did that before and it was working fine, but maybe you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try using `+(BOOL)propertyIsOptional:(NSString*)propertyName`

Comment: Thanks, it did the job so I mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using this on .m file

```
+(BOOL)propertyIsOptional:(NSString*)propertyName
{
    if([propertyName isEqualToString:@"somePropertyNameWhichShouldbeIgnored"])
       return YES;

    return NO;
}
```